# Python Index Error while using arrays and user input

Tags: python, function, user-input

I am using vscode and nothing is underlined in red, but when I run the compiler I get this error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range, for line 16.

```
def QuadraticEquation():
  abc = str(raw_input("In the equation ax^2+bx+c what is a, b, and c (display split each answer up by one space. EX: 1 4 5): "))

  x_axis = raw_input("What is the maximum size of the graph you would like (in units EX: 10): ")

  a,b,c = abc.split()
  a= int(a)
  b=int(b)
  c=int(c)

  x_values = []
  y_values = []
  i=0
  while(i<=x_axis):
    x_values.append(i)
    y_values[i] = ((a*x_values[i]**2) + (b*x_values[i]) +(c))
    i+=1



QuadraticEquation()
```

Comment: Try `append` for `y_values` too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use assignment to an index in the `y_values` list that doesn't exist yet.  In other words, `y_values` is empty to begin with, the first pass through the `while` loop you try to index element `[0]`, which does not yet exist, hence the error.

Change:

```
y_values[i] = ((a*x_values[i]**2) + (b*x_values[i]) +(c))
```

to:

```
y_values.append((a*x_values[i]**2) + (b*x_values[i]) +(c))
```

Comment: It works, thanks so much. I am having problems with the while loop but I can figure that out on my own.